# bag file is empty after rosbag reindexing and fixing .bag.active file

Tags: rosbag, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone!

I'm trying to convert `.bag.active` file into `.bag` file so I can play it inside `rqt_bag` program. The thing is, I tried to follow [this steps](https://answers.ros.org/question/40116/rosbag-file-cannot-be-made-bagactive/) which is to:

1. `rosbag reindex` the `.bag.active` file, and then
2. `rosbag fix` `.bag.active` file into `.bag` file

I do get the message that `Bag migration is successful.` after running `rosbag fix`, but when trying `rosbag play` it says that there are 0 messages to play.

Someone else [also asked](https://answers.ros.org/question/271655/rosbag-reindex-fix-result-in-empty-bag-file/) this question, but there are no answers, so I'm trying again, maybe you can help me.

EDIT: To anybody else reading this question, to recap:

1. run `rosbag record` with `--chunksize=<some_number>` option. `<some_number>` should be a number which is appropriate for how much data in KB you are sending and/or receiving.
2. run `rosbag reindex <your_bag_active_file>`, e.g. `rosbag reindex myfile.bag.active`
3. run `rosbag fix <your_bag_active_file> <new_bag_file_name>`, e.g. `rosbag fix myfile.bag.active mybagfile.bag`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302248/bag-file-is-empty-after-rosbag-reindexing-and-fixing-.bag.active-file/) by [Lucas02](https://answers.ros.org/users/37301/lucas02/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-09-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Reamees](https://answers.ros.org/users/36207/reamees/) on 2018-09-03**:
What is the size of the bag before you fix it?

**Comment by [Lucas02](https://answers.ros.org/users/37301/lucas02/) on 2018-09-03**:
`.bag.active` file is 528,4 kB and `.bag` file after reindex and fix is 4,1 kB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There probably is no actual data in the bag file. I was able to reproduce the problem by terminating the bag in a "not polite way" before the bag had reached the "chunksize". (768kB according to the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#rosbag_record)).

From the wiki:

`--chunksize=SIZE`

```
Advanced. Record to chunks of SIZE KB (Default: 768). This is a buffer within the bag file object. Lowering this value will result in more writes to disk.
```

So I guess anything still in the buffer when the process dies unexpectedly is lost. If you need to work with such small amounts of data and the application is prone to cause recording to crash then you could lower the chunksize.

---

Originally posted by [Reamees](https://answers.ros.org/users/36207/reamees/) with karma: 591 on 2018-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lucas02](https://answers.ros.org/users/37301/lucas02/) on 2018-09-03**:
Ah okay, will try this if it works.

**Comment by [Reamees](https://answers.ros.org/users/36207/reamees/) on 2018-09-03**:
Try it and if it helps you sometimes recover some data then great. In the end it would be best to minimize the need to fix your bags afterward, shutting down the recording of the bag gently, e.g pressing ctrl+c.

**Comment by [Lucas02](https://answers.ros.org/users/37301/lucas02/) on 2018-09-04**:
I can confirm that this works beautifully. Thank you!

**Comment by [Reamees](https://answers.ros.org/users/36207/reamees/) on 2018-09-04**:
Good! Thanks for accepting the answer! It would also be good to keep in mind that reducing the chunksize has some implications. If you start getting more data at some point it might be too much overhead and might cause problems.